# GLSL Lighting math is messed up, cannot find error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have been following the lighting tutorial from learnopengl.com, but for some reason my lighting as been screwed up badly and I don't know why. I have got ambient light to work easily, diffuse is kind of bugged, and specular light is all over the place and I have no idea where to look to fix it.
https://gyazo.com/f66efc10d41806504e9e34f45415bcfe
I also am unsure if my normals have been made correctly. Here is how I generate them with an `std::vector<glm::vec3>` of positions and a `std::vector<unsigned int>` of indices.

```
void ModMesh::generateVertexNormals() {
    if(!positions.empty() || !indices.empty()) {
        normals.clear();
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 3) {
            auto const a = indices[i + 0];
            auto const b = indices[i + 1];
            auto const c = indices[i + 2];
            auto const verta = positions[a];
            auto const vertb = positions[b];
            auto const vertc = positions[c];
            auto const norm = glm::normalize(glm::cross(verta - vertb, vertc - vertb));
            normals.push_back(norm);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I bind my data:

```
void ModMesh::generateVBO_Positions() {
    if(positions.empty()) 
        return;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[VBO::POS]);
    std::vector<float> p;
    for(int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        p.push_back(positions[i].x);
        p.push_back(positions[i].y);
        p.push_back(positions[i].z);
    }
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p.size() * sizeof(float), &p[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

void ModMesh::generateVBO_Normals() {
    if(normals.empty()) 
        return;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[VBO::NORM]);
    std::vector<float> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        n.push_back(positions[i].x);
        n.push_back(positions[i].y);
        n.push_back(positions[i].z);
    }
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n.size() * sizeof(float), &n[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
}
```

Here is my code.

Vertex

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 iPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 iTexcoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 iNormal;

uniform mat4 iProjection;
uniform mat4 iView;
uniform mat4 iModel;

out vec2 texcoord;
out vec3 normal;
out vec3 fragpos;

void main() {
   gl_Position = iProjection * iView * iModel * vec4(iPosition, 1.0);
   texcoord = iTexcoord;
   normal = iNormal;
   fragpos = vec3(iModel * vec4(iPosition, 1.0));
}
```

Fragment

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 fragpos;

uniform sampler2D iTexture;
uniform vec3 iCameraView;
uniform int iUseTexture = 0;
out vec4 outputcolor;

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};
uniform Light iLight;

struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};
uniform Material iMaterial;

void main() {

   float ambientstrength = 0.15;
   float specularstrength = 0.75;

   vec3 norm = normalize(normal);
   vec3 lightdir = normalize(iLight.position - fragpos);

   vec3 ambient = iLight.ambient * iMaterial.ambient;
   vec3 viewdir = normalize(iCameraView - fragpos);
   vec3 reflectdir = reflect(-lightdir, norm);

   float diff = max(dot(norm, lightdir), 0.0);
   float spec = pow(max(dot(viewdir, reflectdir), 0.0), iMaterial.shininess);

   vec3 diffuse = (diff * iMaterial.diffuse) * iLight.diffuse;
   vec3 specular = specularstrength * spec * iLight.specular;
   vec4 light = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);


   outputcolor = mix(vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * light, texture2D(iTexture, texcoord) * light, iUseTexture); 
}
```

C++ snippet, main.cpp:

```
olib::Camera cam(0.0f, 0.5, -3.0f); // My camera object, just the position XYZ
glm::mat4 proj(1.0);
glm::mat4 view(1.0);
glm::mat4 model(1.0);
proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)win.getWidth() / (float)win.getHeight(), 0.1f, 500.0f);

while(win.isOpen()) {
    sh.enable();
    sh.uniformMat4("iProjection", proj);
    sh.uniformMat4("iView", view);
    sh.uniformMat4("iModel", model);
    sh.uniform3f("iCameraView", cam.getPosition());

    sh.uniform3f("iLight.position", 0, 0.5, -3);
    sh.uniform3f("iLight.ambient", 0.14, 0.14, 0.14);
    sh.uniform3f("iLight.diffuse", 0.64, 0.64, 0.64);
    sh.uniform3f("iLight.specular", 0.84, 0.84, 0.84);    
    view = cam.getViewMatrix();
    // Then drawing
}
```

That's as much data that I believe is important. Incase it's not here is a github. https://github.com/LoneC/OpenGL-Project/tree/master

Comment: I'm going to go through in steps. First of all The cross product from the two vector (BA x BC) should be the correct normal of a triangle if in your setup front is CCW.

Comment: Aren't you pushing positions into your normal's buffer in ModMesh::generateVBO_Normals()?

Comment: No, im pushing the value of `glm::normalize(glm::cross(verta - vertb, vertc - vertb));` in the vector normals.

Comment: But you're loading into the VBO from the positions array! See: "void ModMesh::generateVBO_Normals()"

Comment: You're possibly going to have errors about normal VBO being shorter than positions VBO and its natural, see my answer.

Comment: In your fragment shader the light calculations are done in worldspace, so you a have to transform the normal vector to worldspace too (as you do it with the fragment position. `normal = transpose(inverse (mat3(iModel))) * iNormal;` or at least `normal = mat3(iModel) * iNormal;`. For now this is no problem, because your model matrix is the identity matrix, but this will become an issue later.

Comment: To direct the normal vectors always to the camera, try `vec3 norm = normalize(normal) * sign(dot(normal,viewdir));`

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you're on the right track with this procedure:
"void ModMesh::generateVertexNormals()". You're generating the front facing normal of each triangle for a front = CCW setup of OpenGL. The thing is, you're generating one normal per triangle and in your vertex shader the normal is passed per vertex. But in your case you generate 1 normal per triangle! What you should after is go through each vertex position, and for each triangle which uses that position get their normal, and then average that normal. That way you smooth out the normals of the triangles at each vertex. Let me explain in a more graphical manner:
[image]

I must add that you're also currently uploading the positions into the VBO normals, but that's what i was telling you about in the comments.

If you actually want flat shading, then, as far as I can think of right now, you gotta ditch the indices and use 3 positions per triangle, each with normals taken from your current normal generation method, triplicated into each position just like in step two of my paint drawing. Pardon my paint by the way.

Comment: Aw darn, I thought I was generating vertex normals. As for the positions being pushed into the normals in `ModMesh::generateVBO_Normals`, I have fixed that. Here is the result I have currently. (Have not yet fixed vertex normals, I have to figure out how to do that now...) https://gyazo.com/7edb2fa481ccdb73ca390a054ac2b649

Comment: Since it seems you're investigating the subject, I decided not to give you code but a hint into the algorithm... Its just a tiny tad more complicated than what you've already accomplished, just a few extra steps looking out for which triangles use each given position (by looking at the indices), and add up the normals you've already generated for those triangles and re-normalize them! Ok I shut up now and let you do your work =]

Comment: By the way it looks way better now, I believe because some of the normals are actually matching the normals each position should have if you were using flat shading, but It should be completely fixed after you code the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me out :)